# Collider2D vs Collision2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

After doing some video tutorials on Youtube, I recognized that these two Classes look similar and repetitive.

-Collision2D-

This method called when an incoming collider makes contact with this object's collider (2D physics only)

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
            coll.gameObject.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", 10);

    }
```

-Collider2D-

This method called when another collider makes contact with this object

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    Destroy (other.gameObject);
}
```

Both methods have same purpose and look the same. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

`Collision2D` contains the info about the collision, while `Collider2D` is a component of the colliding object.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html

As you can see, the purpose is similar, but not the same.

Comment: i still confused about Collision2D. What i means is i can see and easily create Collider2D object in UI but where can i create a Collision2D object? Sorry for my newbie question. haha.

Comment: @ggDeGreat, you don't create a Collision2D object. That's the class that gets passed to you when you handle that event OnCollisionEnter and the event occurs... It's created by the 2d physics system in unity engine. Through that you can find out collision points for example.

Comment: i see. one more things, those two methods, even it pass different class, but both will gain access to all info for Collision right? the different is one method called during trigger, and the other one is not.

Comment: @ggDeGreat, AFAIK Collider2D doesn't have access to info which points were actually in the collision or the relative velocity (yet you can probably calculate this one yourself).. It pretty much depends on what you need.