# Unity - Convert Collider2D to Collision2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two functions, one is OnCollisionEnter2D and one is OnTriggerEnter2D. I need to convert Collision2D to Collider2D or vice versa:

```
//  c# script
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    foo(collision);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {
    foo(collider);
}

void foo(Collision2D coll){
    //checking inside here
}
```

Of course, this isn't going to compile because i am giving foo collider, and collider isn't a Collision2D. [I have noticed that these two data types are almost the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800678/collider2d-vs-collision2d). I can't cast these two. Could someone please help me convert or suggest a workaround?

Thanks in advance!!

**Edit:**

This is my checking code...

```
int coins;

void Start(){
    coins = 0;
}

void foo(Collision2D coll){
    if(coll.gameObject.tag == "coin"){
        coins++;
    }
//this works for both Collision2D and Collider2D because both have the gameObject property

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generic methode

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    foo<Collision2D>(collision);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    foo<Collider2D>(collider);
}


public void foo<T>(T c)
{
    GameObject g;

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Collider2D))
    {
        Collider2D obj = (Collider2D)(object)c;
        g = obj.gameObject;
    }
    else {
        Collision2D obj = (Collision2D)(object)c;
        g = obj.gameObject;
    }

    Debug.Log(g.tag);

    if (g.tag == "coin")
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an overload method for `foo()` like this:

```
//  c# script
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    foo(collision);
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {
    foo(collider);
}

void foo(Collision2D coll){
    //checking inside here
}


void foo(Collider2D coll){

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great... is there a way I can do this without having to copy and paste code between the two overloads?

Comment: Well. TBH a collider component can only behave as a trigger or a collider. So registering `OnCollisionEnter()` and `OnTriggerEnter()` both for one collider component is useless. I can help more if you tell me what you are trying to do actually so please post implementation of `foo()` as well.

Comment: And when you are working on performance critical code like in game development, try to write optimized and efficient code by doing less calculation. Having duplicate code is not a big deal here.